# React hooks useEffect with a condition timer

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, use-effect

Is the below code correct when useEffect has a condition setTimout?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (condition) {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            func1()
        }, 1000)
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer)
        }
    }
    func2()
    return () => {}
}, [])
```

Comment: Where do `func1` and `func2` come from? Those are dependencies to this `useEffect` and so should be listed in the dependencies array.